# How do i extract xml data stored as data in a table column with a complex formed sql

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I have  XML data that comes in from a third party (so I cannot change the XML format) and gets stored in a table.

An example XML message format

```
<MedicalAidMessage xmlns="test.co.za/messaging" version="6.0">
  <BenefitCheckResponseMessage>
    <FinancialResponseDetails>
      <FinancialResponseLines>
        <FinancialResponseLine>
          <LineIdentifier>1</LineIdentifier>
          <RequestedAmount>1000</RequestedAmount>
          <AmountToProvider>800</AmountToProvider>
          <AmountToMember>0</AmountToMember>
          <MemberLiableAmount>200</MemberLiableAmount>
          <MemberNotLiableAmount>0</MemberNotLiableAmount>
          <TariffCode>12345</TariffCode>
          <LineResponseCodes>
            <LineResponseCode>
              <Sequence>1</Sequence>
              <Code>274</Code>
              <Description>We have not paid the amount claimed because the funds in the Medical Savings are used up.</Description>
              <Type>Info</Type>
            </LineResponseCode>
            <LineResponseCode>
              <Sequence>2</Sequence>
              <Code>1239</Code>
              <Description>We have applied a co-payment on this claim, in line with the member’s plan benefit for MRI and CT scans.</Description>
              <Type>Info</Type>
            </LineResponseCode>
          </LineResponseCodes>
        </FinancialResponseLine>
      </FinancialResponseLines>
    </FinancialResponseDetails>
  </BenefitCheckResponseMessage>
</MedicalAidMessage>
```

I have tried the following code to get the Tariffcode, RequestedAmount, AmountToProvider and AmountToMember

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML = (select top 1  replace(br.xmlmessage,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','')
                              from benefitcheckresponse br
                                inner join benefitcheck bc on bc.id = br.BenefitCheckId
                             where bc.id =1562
```

order by bc.id desc)

```
    SELECT
        [TariffCode] = Node.Data.value('TariffCode', 'vacrhar(50)'),
        [RequestedAmount] = Node.Data.value('RequestedAmount', 'float)'),
        [AmountToProvider] = Node.Data.value('AmountToProvider', 'float)'),
        [AmountToMember] = Node.Data.value('AmountToMember', 'float)')
        FROM @XMLData.nodes('/*/FinancialResponseLine/') Node(Data)
```

The problem I am getting is that it is giving me the following error message

> Msg 9341, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 XQuery [nodes()]: Syntax error
> near '', expected a step expression.

How do I resolve that error?

How would I include the results for multiple lines when there multiple line responses?

How would I include the values from the sub nodes to the line response nodes?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off with syntax like this, if I am honest. I wasn't able to complete the `ORDER BY` clause for you, as I don't know what column to order by, but as you have a `TOP (1)` you **need** one. You also need to define your XML namespace, which you have not, which would have resulted in no rows being returned:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'test.co.za/messaging')
SELECT TOP (1)
       FRL.FRL.value('(TariffCode/text())[1]','int') AS TariffCode,
       FRL.FRL.value('(RequestedAmount/text())[1]','int') AS RequestedAmount, --I doubt float is the correct data type here
       FRL.FRL.value('(AmountToProvider/text())[1]','int') AS AmountToProvider, --I doubt float is the correct data type here
       FRL.FRL.value('(AmountToMember/text())[1]','int') AS AmountToMember --I doubt float is the correct data type here
FROM dbo.benefitcheckresponse br
     INNER JOIN benefitcheck bc ON bc.id = br.BenefitCheckId
     CROSS APPLY br.xmlmessage.nodes('MedicalAidMessage/BenefitCheckResponseMessage/FinancialResponseDetails/FinancialResponseLines/FinancialResponseLine') FRL(FRL)
WHERE bc.id = 1562
ORDER BY {Column Name(s)};
```

Comment: That doesn't work since the bc column is defined as varchar, not XML and I cannot change the definition.  As for the order by, its for the bc table, so by bc.id desc

Comment: *"bc column is defined as varchar"* Your question doesn't state that, @MarcL ; you just tell us it's XML and thus why would we assume you are *not* using the `xml` data type?. You'll need to therefore `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value to `xml`, likely with use `VALUES` table construct.

Comment: As you see in my original code I saved the column to an XML variable.  Its why I did that, to change the saved Varchar to xml